# Connect Django to existing Docker Postgres container

Tags: django, python-2.7, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a situation where I need to connect my Django project to an existing Docker Postgres container. In simple words, when I execute `python manage.py dbshell`, django should connect to an existing Docker Postgres container.
Currently my django is connected to sqlite3 db. Below is my `settings.py` snippet for connecting to db.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
#       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
#       'NAME': 'etag_auth',
#       'USER': 'etag_master',
#       'PASSWORD': 'thisismypass',
#       'HOST': 'cybercom_postgres',
#       'PORT': '5432'
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
#       'etag': {
#       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
#       'NAME': 'etag',
#       'USER': 'etag_master',
#       'PASSWORD': 'thisismypass',
#       'HOST': 'cybercom_postgres',
#       'PORT': '5432',
#    }
}
```

I also tried with docker-compose, but i am not able to make docker-compose to connect to existing container.
Below is my docker-compose.yml code snippet

```
postgres:
  external:
   name: etag_postgres
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - /data/db
```

Kindly help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first problem is **HOST** in your configuration.

```
'HOST': 'cybercom_postgres',
```

Host should be IP Address of you database located, if all entire project and database are in the same server, localhost should work.
`'HOST': 'localhost'`  or your docker image name `'HOST': 'postgres'`